# AWS CloudWatch retention

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Is it possible using AWS CloudWatch to set a retention policy to keep a rolling with all log entries with custom metric of for example, the last three months?
From what I unterstand reading the docs, retention policies only allow to retain e.g. Data points with a period of 60 seconds for 15 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data retention is standard for all CloudWatch metrics and cannot be customized. Basically, it's a way for AWS to reduce the amount of data they store, by reducing the resolution of the data that is kept.

It's also worth mentioning that CloudWatch will *never* provide the raw datapoints. Instead, it will only return **computed metrics**, such as the SUM or AVERAGE over a period of time. So, it will never provide "all log entries", even for recently created data.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a link in AWS docs where is explained? Also does this apply to CloudWatch Logs? How does this qualify CloudWatch for detailed Application Logging?

Comment: For "detailed Application Logging", use CloudWatch Logs. It maintains all the contents of the logs. Normal "CloudWatch" (not CloudWatch Logs) is for metrics, which are provided as computed values over a period of time. See: [Amazon CloudWatch Concepts - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#Statistic)